# Android GMaps application

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple map application with GMaps API. When I installed the APK to Android device, the application has stopped working. What's wrong?

This is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.kddhlab.lecullinaire;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
```

}

this is the layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kddhlab.lecullinaire"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<permission
android:name="com.kddhlab.lecullinaire.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.kddhlab.lecullinaire.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyADB5Bu16kTY-7_XZy8_qZBdAwVyGKq0sU"/>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.kddhlab.lecullinaire.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: read the crash log stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide to get started then when its working: start manipulate the code.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Good luck :)